# 32bit Jpeg wont display correctly on my TImage?

Tags: delphi, image, bitmap, 32-bit, 24-bit

how can i convert 32bit jpeg image in 24bit? or convert it into 24bit bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build in library does not support 32-bit jpeg. Try the [nativejpg library](http://www.simdesign.nl/nativejpg.html). see also [handling CMYK jpeg files in Delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143543/handling-cmyk-jpeg-files-in-delphi-7)